# systemd based automount never umounts when idle

Tags: autofs, sles12

The setup (not autofs, but systemd based automount):

```
# grep automount /etc/fstab
1.2.3.4:/vol/homedirs /home/roaming nfs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=30
```

and:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

on SLES12.3.

This works great! If a user logs in, having "/home/roaming/someuser123" homedir, the /home/roaming gets automatically mounted. it wasn't mounted before.

**The question**: after user logs out, the "/home/roaming" never gets umounted! Why? The "x-systemd.idle-timeout=30" syntax looks good!

**UPDATES**:

```
# systemctl status automount
? automount.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
#
```

Comment: Please show the automount unit if you have one.

Comment: updated the question! Thanks.

Comment: I am the first one who wants to use autofs/automounts timeout function? :)

Comment: You didn't have a generated automount unit for your mount point? I see that for some reason you ran `systemctl status automount` but I don't know why, as that doesn't exist and isn't what I asked for. Look in `/run/systemd/generator` for a unit corresponding to your automount, for example `home-roaming.automount`.

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me (on Ubuntu):

1. Clean start: make sure the mount point is not mounted yet.
2. Have the mount defined in your `/etc/fstab`
3. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. `sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target`

To check if it works:

At this point if you didn't access the remote filesystem yet, `systemctl status home-roaming.mount` should report `Loaded: loaded` and `Active: inactive (dead)`. Next, access the filesystem, with e.g. `ls /home/roaming`. Rerunning the above status query should now report  `Active: active (mounted)`. If the mount point is truly not accessed by the system after the user logs out, it should get umounted after the idle timeout, with corresponding active status. If not, I would try next with a mount point that is not a user homedir to see if it makes a difference.